# Google AppEngine HRD -- consistency vs contention?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datastore

I am trying to model a simple diagram editor that stores data into GAE's HRD datastore, and I am facing problems that I am wondering if you can give me some advices on.  Basically, the editor's model are:

[Diagram] --contains--> [Shapes] -- contains--> [Text]

Initially, I put these into the same entity group, to make sure the data is consistent.  By doing so, whenever I add new shapes or add text objects to existing shapes, they show up properly (as it's queried from datastore); however, I am having problem because the user could be adding many shapes quickly, and that leads to more than one update to the diagram object per second, which leads to write contention.

Alternatively, I could design like so:

[Diagram]    [ Shape - contains diagramId]   [ Text - contains shapeId]

which put them in different entity group, and when I create a new shape I just have to save the shape object itself.  This solves the write contention problem, but the data is no longer consistent -- depending on how soon HRD commits the write, I might get stale data.

I tried combinations such as putting the diagrams in the cache, and retrieve from the HRD only if the cache doesn't contain the diagram; however, this is unpredictable as I can't be sure that the diagram would be in the cache (I expect many diagrams to be edited at the same time)...

What's the best practice on dealing with such issue?  I am using Java and JDO, if that makes any difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few notes:

1. HRD reads are strongly consistent if you use `get` and eventually consistent if you use `query` (as queries rely on indexes and those need time to be built). You can get around your problem by using `get`, if possible.
2. If Texts and Shapes are part of one Diagram and if you do not need to access them separatelly AND you do not need to search by Text's or Shape's properties, then you could just serialize Text and Shape inside a Diagram. I use Objectify and this is simply achieved with the `@Serialize` annotation on a field (don't know about JDO as I don't use it).

Comment: +1 for mentioning objectify -- @adrian, I would urge you to consider dropping JDO and moving to objectify. It will handle memcaching for you in a consistant manner.